# Mat Tooltip multiline

Tags: html, css, angular

I cannot get the mat Tooltip to show on multiline no matter what I do it seems to ignore all of my attempts. I have tried newline \n, 
, and now this code of &#13.

Can someone help with this?

```
  <span [matTooltipClass]="new-lines"
               matTooltip="I am on line 1&#13; I should be on Line 2">
               <i class="fas fa-sync" style="color: white;"></i>
     </span>

::ng-deep .new-lines  {
  white-space: pre-line    !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a property binding to pass class to tooltip:

```
[matTooltipClass]="new-lines"
       /               \
 @Input name          expression
```

As you can see Angular thinks that you're passing the result of `new - lines` expression. It means that you should have two properties defined in your component: `new` and `lines`

Obviously, it is not what you expected to happen. You need to pass `'new-lines'` string.

You have many options here:

```
matTooltipClass="new-lines"

[matTooltipClass]="'new-lines'"

bind-matTooltipClass="'new-lines'"
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pqsf9l?file=src/app/tooltip-overview-example.html)**